# Discord Bot returning "HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Cannot send an empty message" although I am sending a non-empty message

Tags: python, http, bots, discord, discord.py

So i'm new to the whole discord bot scene and i'm trying to print a function return value into a discord server from this bot i'm working on.

I have this function that just returns the string that is passed in:

```
def returnParameter(string):
    return string
```

and when I try to call this function as a command to my bot in my discord server
by typing in for example `.bot hello world!`, the following code is executed:

```
@client.command(aliases = ["bot", "BOT"])
async def botFunction(ctx, *, command):
    response = returnParameter(command)
    await ctx.send(print(response))
```

Using the above example, I expected my discord server to print out `"hello world!"`
but instead I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 860, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 698, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 72, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Cannot send an empty message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your function and your command seem to have the same name.  You should give them different names.
2. `print(response)` returns `None`.  You should just be doing `await ctx.send(response)`

Comment: Wow, it worked: my first problem was my fault, when copying the information over on stack but the second problem I didnt really think about... Why dont we use print, how would the discord function know to print the string out if we don't explicitly tell it?

Comment: `ctx.send` is what sends the message to discord.  If you also want to print the string to a console or log you should do that on a separate line.